# satisfactory vs optimal decision making

Tags: optimization, multi-objective-optimization

In most classical game theoretic problems (situations in which more than one decision maker impacts the state of the environment), we assume that the decision-makers optimize their objective function. However, in most real decision-making problems, people look for a satisfactory solution instead of an optimal solution. For example, when someone wants to decide to buy something, they may rarely optimize a cost function; rather, they choose a satisfactory option. In this regard, we should look for methodologies that find satisfactory solutions. This can be done when we have human interference in the decision-making process. Usually, in regular (less important) decision making, the human mind might look for a satisfactory solution because finding that does not have computational burden. I am thinking about how we can formulate such a thing.

How can we analyze such games?

Is it possible to have a few satisfactory solution-finding approaches instead of optimization methods that mimic what really happens in the human mind during regular decision making?

Comment: I think what you are after is some sort of feasibility problem: If you can quantify what is enough to qualify as *satisfactory*, then you can add that as a requirement for solutions to be feasible. The "objective function" is then simply a constant, meaning any solution meeting the threshold of "satisfactory" is an optimal.

Comment: "_I would be happy to hear your opinion about these matters._"  This is not the site for opinions.  See the [tour] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If I am buying a car, I do *not* just choose a satisfactory option; I choose the best option I can find *within some time and effort limits*. Those limits are not easily quantified, since they depend on mood, other demands on my time, etc. The analog in optimization is setting a time or iteration limit and taking the (not necessarily provably optimal) final incumbent solution.

Comment: I believe the type of problems that you explained fall within the "Multi Attribute Decision Making (MADM)" category where you have limited number of options/candidates among them you would like to choose one (or even rank/categorize all) based on some attributes (price, time, effort, or any other quality that can be somehow quantified).

Comment: In MADM problem, we have countable options. However, in this problem, we may uncountable number of options in  the feasible set. @OguzToragay